# Like button and Like box not showing only on some pages of my site. On the rest it works fine

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-likebox

I'm going into my third hour of trying to figure out what went wrong on my pages, and I'm still at ground zero.
The like buttons and like box doesn't show up anymore, and facebook comments count doesn't show up either.
It worked fine last night, and this morning they just don't want to work anymore.

Works on:
http://www.purelie.com/post/42
Doesn't work on:
http://www.purelie.com/user/Qloudify
and on homepage ( can't link more than 2 links, just click on the logo ).

If anyone has any idea about this.. any hint or idea is helpful.
The like buttons are identical, so is the like box and the fb-root. I just don't know what to do next to make it work.
Thank you in advance.

I have fixed it. It was the facebook comments count that was breaking everything. Somehow last night the facebook devs broke the count and it was throwing errors, stopping any other FB js to work.
What I did: I commented the facebook comments count until they fix it and I removed << xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#" >> from the head. Works fine now

Comment: HTML structure is not same on these pages. Whether these pages are suppose to have the same structure? I am referring to the div containing the FB links

Comment: the page structure is supposed to be different, /post/ shows a single post, /user/ shows all the user's posts ( multiple ) and homepage shows all recent, so they are supposed to be slightly different, but the actual facebook buttons and counts are identical.

Answer (score 0):

It's not showing on the second link because there's a javascript exception on the page that's causing the rest of the script not to fire. Open the second page in something like Chrome, and press F12 to open the developer tools. If you click in the console tab, you'll see an error stating: "No polyfill registered for object".

If you can fix whatever's causing that error, your like buttons should appear again. It looks like it might be to do with the HTML being different for the like button between the two pages, but I can't say for 100% without going through the code in more detail.

Comment: I found out what was wrong. It was the comments count. ( <fb:comments-count href=http://example.com/></fb:comments-count> ). Apparently facebook devs somehow broke the comments count last night. It doesn't work on their site either. ( http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/ ). Scroll down to FAQ, that's what I've been using. Thank you for the help!